# How to solve ParameterMissing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am getting the following error, when i try to submit in my _follow.html.rb form and can't figure out why the params aren't being passed.

I got:

ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#update

param is missing or the value is empty: user

```
   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation, :followed_user)
   end
```

This is the request

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"LOnA6CA3yQYaCDqme6OkxPZlkBRvybhYANreU3BxuV8=",
 "followed_user"=>"#<User:0x007f4e902fcf20>",
 "commit"=>"Follow",
 "id"=>"57f2b32b717f01297dda1759"}
```

Bellow is the view

```
<%= form_for(current_user) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_user, @user %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

And this is my User model

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :followers, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :following
  has_and_belongs_to_many :following, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :followers


  field :name, type: String
  field :email, type: String
  field :password_digest, :type => String
  field :admin, type: Boolean, default: false
  field :created_at, type: Date, default: Time.current

  has_secure_password 


  def feed
    microposts
  end

# Follows a user.
  def follow(other_user)
    following << other_user
  end

  # Unfollows a user.
  def unfollow(other_user)
    following.delete(other_user)
  end

  # Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
  def is_following?(other_user)
    following.include?(other_user)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the 'f' variable from the block to generate the `hidden_field_tag` to ensure it submits a `user` param.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :followed_user_id %>
```

But, you may have other issues that you'll need to deal with.  You'll need a method on the user instance to handle getting and setting followed_user_id.  Not sure that makes sense considering there are many followings.

Also, this will send a request the `update` method and that may not be what you want.  Instead, you may want it to send the request to the `followings` controller `create` method - this would be RESTful.  That's a separate question, though.  This should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need your form to have "@user" in the for instead of "current user".

So in the form change

```
<%= form_for(current_user) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
```